# Cycle Through Text on button click with link at end jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a complete novice at jQuery and all that comes with it! So I'm attempting to create a button that when clicked, disappears and a cycle of text rotates and at the end of that cycle, a link appears for the user to then click onto.

I've got the base cycle of text down but I'm so stuck! Is anyone able to help me with this? Thank you so much!

```js
var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
  i = 0;

(function cycle() {

  divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
    .delay(1000)
    .fadeOut(400, cycle);

  i = ++i % divs.length;

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button">Process</div>
<div id="content-1">stage 1</div>
<div id="content-2">stage 2</div>
<div id="content-3">stage 3</div>
<div id="content-4">stage 4</div>
<div id="content-5">stage 5</div>
<a href="google.com">Your link</a>
```

Comment: Can you be more clear? or at least create a button then start to code of that buttons actions. Remember, JQuery is not a language. You have to use javascript.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear! It's a bit tricky to explain...

I wanted to create a button that when a user clicks it, the button hides and the stage 1, stage 2 etc starts cycling through until it hits stage 5, then after that the text disappears and a url is displayed afterwards.

Comment: Where is your button's html? where you gonna place it? what will be your button's id or class or any thing else can be a selector? these are important. you need to show more efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume to have got the solutoin to your problem. You can try:

```js
        function cycle(ele, i) {
            if (ele.length > 0 && i < ele.length) {
                $(ele[i]).fadeIn(400, function() {
                    $(this).delay(1000).fadeOut(400, function() {
                        cycle(ele, i + 1);
                    });
                });
            } else {
                $('a[id^="link-"]').show();
            }
        }
        $(function() {
            $('div[id^="content-"]').hide();
            $('a[id^="link-"]').hide();
            $('#button').click(function() {
                $(this).hide();
                cycle($('div[id^="content-"]'), 0);
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button">Process</button>
<div id="content-1">stage 1</div>
<div id="content-2">stage 2</div>
<div id="content-3">stage 3</div>
<div id="content-4">stage 4</div>
<div id="content-5">stage 5</div>
<a id="link-1" href="google.com">Your link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help too! Much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('a').hide();
var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
      i = -1;

$("#button").click(function()
{  
  $(this).hide();
  (function cycle() {   
       if(i < divs.length - 1)
             i = ++i % divs.length;
          else
          {
            $('a').show();   
              return;
          }

          divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
                    .delay(1000)
                    .fadeOut(400, cycle);           

  })();    

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/86829ryz/16/

Comment: Obviously div id button supposed to be a button. you caught that when i couldn't :)

Comment: I wasn't sure why you were using a div instead of button. So I kept the code the way it was :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It's sorted what I needed! You're a legend :)